# Add sub page option is not available in salesforce org community builder

Tags: community, page-layout, community-builder, napili, winter21

I was trying to **create** a **sub-page** for the **main pages** in the **community builder**.

- I am using a customer service template.

But that option to create that is not available in my **test dev org** *whereas* it is available in my **full sandbox**.

Below is the image from the full sandbox.

[image]

*Please help me how to **enable** this **in my dev org**.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The add subpage functionality you are seeing in your full sandbox org is part of the Salesforce Winter'21 release. Once the Winter'21 is rolled out on your Developer edition org, you will be able to see the same.

See release notes https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_networks_page_actions.htm for more details.

To add, as not all pages are created equal, not all pages can have subpages. These pages include:

1. Home
2. Error
3. Object pages (Example "Case" object page does not have option to add subpages whereas "Contact Support" has option to add subpage from the UI)
4. Content pages
5. Login pages

You can follow the [steps in link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317969&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) to identify the release of your salesforce org